# Autotools: PROGRAMS installation paths

Tags: autotools, automake

In the typical case, when you need to build binaries and install them I could use something like:

```
bin_PROGMRAMS: foo
foo_SOURCES: goo.c
```

or

```
sbin_PROGRAMS: foo
foo_SOURCES: goo.c
```

This means that foo will be built, and then be installed in `$(prefix)/bin` or `$(prefix)/sbin`. However, if instead of `bin_PROGRAMS` you use `data_PROGRAMS` automake will not allow this.

The question: What is the full list of paths that are allowed for binaries ("PROGRAMS") installation?

Answer (score 1):

The full list of predefined installation directories allowed for `PROGRAMS` is:

```
‘bindir’, ‘sbindir’, ‘libexecdir’, ‘pkglibdir’
```

Full list of similar standard paths can be found in the [auto-book](https://www.sourceware.org/autobook/autobook/autobook_76.html)

**EDIT: the list above is not correct, I'm leaving it here just to give context to the comment section**, see below:

It appears the auto-book is outdated. the correct list of installation directories is:

```
bindir, sbindir, libexecdir, pkglibexecdir
```

https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/html_node/Program-Sources.html#Program-Sources

Comment: You seem to have copied your list from the Autobook, which turns out to be wrong on this count, as you can verify by experiment.  `pkglibdir` is **not** a valid directory for use with the `PROGRAMS` primary, as indeed is consistent with the allowed uses of `libdir`.  I imagine that the Autobook meant to say `pkglibexecdir` instead, which otherwise constitutes an omission.  In any event, the primary source for this information would be [the Automake manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html#Uniform).

Comment: @JohnBollinger Yes, it is from autobook, as I actually stated in the answer. I checked the link you've supplied and it doesn't seem to list the directories that are considered fine to install PROGRAMS in by automake...

Comment: The key issue here is that the answer presented is demonstrably ***wrong***.  `pkglibdir` is not allowed for `PROGRAMS`, and `pkglibexecdir` is. The Automake manual section I linked provides the correct information in part by reference to [the GNU Coding Standards](https://www.gnu.org/prep/standards/standards.html#Directory-Variables), and in part by remarking that "Automake extends this list with pkgdatadir, pkgincludedir, pkglibdir, and pkglibexecdir; these are the same as the non-‘pkg’ versions, but with ‘$(PACKAGE)’ appended."

Comment: Ok, found the right place with the answer (edited the answer accordingly)